# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cov_probe_v12: cov_probe_12

Tags: teamcity, bullseye

The solution without bullseye builds fine but when bulleye is enabled it says LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cov_probe_v12. I have upgraded bullseye to latest 8.11.6 version but still does not help. Please let me know if you have a solution. I tried the solution in https://simplyged.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/bullseye-coverage-and-cov_prove_v12-error/ but didn't work!

Comment: Please clarify: What are you working on? You are using Teamcity - which version? I would recommend that you first introduce a little bit more what you are working, followed by some technical details about the used Teamcity and Bullseye version. After that you should explain what actions you perform to get the error.

Comment: Hi I am using teamcity 9.1.3 and I'm trying to build a solution using commandline where I specify the parameter to enable/disable bullseye . When bullseye is enabled I get the above error.

Comment: When I get messages like this, the first thing I try is to re-build the whole project, and most of the time that's it. I think it is problematic to link bullseye instrumented code to non-instrumented code.

Comment: I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it, a lot of times but did not work actually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I tried "Rebuild Solution" (and not just "Build Solution") and it worked fine for me, you should try that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing the library links in your build process. Maybe try adding the `--lib` option to covc.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with Visual Studio, Just try out the following steps.

1. Open Bullseye Coverage Browser from Start Menu
2. Goto Tools-> Options
3. Enable the corresponding visual c++ versions you are working with in the build tab and then Press OK.
4. Then try to clean and build your solution.

Hope this helps!!!